# Inner Join Results in TSQL

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have three tables that I am working with and I am having trouble getting just what I need.

The tables are called Documents, Variable, and VariableValue. Documents has a primary key DocumentID, VariableValue and Variable has as primary key VariableID and VariableValue also has DocumentID as a primary key. The following query gives very close to what I need. Additionally it controls the return of versions of a file to the latest one.

```
Select Distinct vv.ValueCache as 'Company Name'
from VariableValue vv, Documents d
where d.DocumentID = vv.DocumentID and
vv.VariableID =  (Select VariableID
                   from Variable
                   where  VariableName  = 'Supplier Type' and d.Deleted = 0) and 
vv.RevisionNo = (Select Max( Vv1.RevisionNo)
                  From VariableValue vv1 
                  where vv1.VariableID = vv.VariableID and
                        vv1.DocumentID = d.DocumentID and
                        vv1.ValueText is not null)  and
vv.ValueCache != ''
```

What I really want to get is a list of files in which a column called 'Supplier Type' (called out in Variable table) does **not** have the value 'Distributor' contained in the VariableValues.ValueText column. I feel like I am very close, I just can't figure out how to get the Distributor argument in the call.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, an explanation of what you want (rather than something "close") and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: specify the DBMS.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & 

specificversions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your 

particularstrings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover 

to yoursearches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as 

title &keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do 

have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not 100% sure what you're asking for. MOre specifically, I'm not sure what you mean by "get the Distributor argument in the call", but it sounds like what you're looking for is just something like `WHERE vv1.ValueText <> 'Distributor'` or possibly something like a `NOT IN` clause. 
For example,

`<your query> ... WHERE vv1.ValueText NOT IN (select * from dbo.MyTable where vv1.ValueText <> 'Distributor')`

`IN` might be a good thing to look into. If you can provide sample tables, that would be a lot more helpful.

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. I will take your approach and see what happens Thank you. I will get sample tables if I don't make headway.

Comment: Please do not answer unclear questions, use comments to ask for clarification. Guessing answers to unclear questions makes messes.